# Perl directory is getting past if(! -d) statement? [readdir results]

Tags: perl, if-statement, directory

Okay so I have a program that basically looks into a passed in directory, if any file names match a pattern I will make a directory and move that specific file and any that matches it (regardless of extension) into that directory. Now if they don't match I should move them into the `PassedInDir/misc/` directory.

I have a condition in both cases to avoid passing in any directory (as my program isn't ready to deal with those yet) something like `if( ! -d $fp)`.

Everything works fine when I run it the first time in the directory. However when I run it again on the same directory (which should now only contain directories) I get the Error `Could not move file assignmentZ to destination DataB/misc at projectSorter.pl line 16.`. AssignmentZ is a directory however its somehow getting past the `(!-d)` in the second case.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use File::Copy;
if(@ARGV < 1){
    print "\nUsage: proj6.pl <directory>\n\n";
    exit;
}
die("\nDirectory $ARGV[0] does not exist\n\n") if( ! -e $ARGV[0]);
opendir( DIR, $ARGV[0]) or die("\nCould not open directory $ARGV[0]\n\n");
while(($fp = readdir(DIR))){
    if($fp =~ m/proj(.*)\./){
        (! -d "$ARGV[0]/assignment$1") && (mkdir "$ARGV[0]/assignment$1");
        move("$ARGV[0]/$fp" , "$ARGV[0]/assignment$1") or die("Could not move file $fp to destination $ARGV[0]/assignment$1");
    }
    elsif(! -d $fp){  #gets past here!!!
        (! -d "$ARGV[0]/misc") && (mkdir "$ARGV[0]/misc");
        move("$ARGV[0]/$fp" , "$ARGV[0]/misc") or die("Could not move file $fp to destination $ARGV[0]/misc");
    }
}
```

It is the only directory to do it out of the ones previously made by running my program once. I am curious about why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$fp` as set by `readdir` is relative to scanned directory. `chdir` to the scanned directory or prepend the scanned directory name for `-d` test.

You use `"$ARGV[0]/$fp"` as argument to move function.

`perldoc -f readdir`

> readdir DIRHANDLE
>               Returns the next directory entry for a directory opened by
>               "opendir". […]
>               If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a
>               "readdir", you'd better prepend the directory in question.
>               Otherwise, because we didn't "chdir" there, it would have been
>               testing the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

‣ Don't use the -w flag with Perl. Some modules turn warnings off to do their work but the -w flag is global. With it, they will report warnings that should be ignored.

‣ Always have these two lines at the top of every script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

These will catch a lot of errors in your code. See [`perldoc strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`perldoc warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) for more details.

‣ Use [`glob()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) or [`Find::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) instead of opendir/readdir/closedir.

‣ Use  `make_path()` from [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) instead of `mkdir`.

‣ Use an `if` statement for conditional execution instead of `&&`.

‣ Place blank lines in your code to make reading it easier.

`File::Find` and `File::path` are standard modules that come installed with Perl. For a list of the standard modules, see [`perldoc perlmodlib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# --------------------------------------
# pragmas

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------
# modules
use File::Copy;
use File::Path   qw( make_path );

# --------------------------------------
# main

# make sure there is something to work on
if(@ARGV < 1){
    print "\nUsage: proj6.pl <directory>\n\n";
    exit;
}

# arguments should be directories
for my $src_dir ( @ARGV ){

    # validate the source directory
    die("\n$src_dir does not exist\n\n")     if( ! -e $src_dir);
    die("\n$src_dir is not a directory\n\n") if( ! -d $src_dir);

    # move proj* files
    for my $proj ( glob( "$src_dir/proj*" )){

        # get the proj number
        ( my $number ) = $proj =~ m/proj(.*)\./;

        # get the destination directory
        my $dst_dir = "$src_dir/assignment$number";

        # create the directory where it goes
        if( ! -d $dst_dir ){
            make_path( $dst_dir ) or die "could not make path $dst_dir";
        }

        # move the file
        move( $proj, $dst_dir ) or die( "could not move file $proj to destination $dst_dir" );

    } # end of $proj files

    # move other files
    for my $file ( grep { ! -d } glob( "$src_dir/*" )){

        # get the destination directory
        my $dst_dir = "$src_dir/misc";

        # create the directory where it goes
        if( ! -d $dst_dir ){
            make_path( $dst_dir ) or die "could not make path $dst_dir";
        }

        # move the file
        move( $file, $dst_dir ) or die( "could not move file $file to destination $dst_dir" );

    } # end other files

} # end of src_dir
```